# Unknown key in field steams - meteor-files

Tags: mongodb, meteor, file-upload

I work on Meteor and trying to upload an image and put it on.

I followed the [guide from here](https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files) but I get an error before the upload starts.

```
error message: "Match error: Unknown key in field steams"
```

I put the API file and the function in React in this gist repo.

https://gist.github.com/fadimoubassaleh/f68aeb01b65d81b341a1fec9a71027fe

Many thanks.

Comment: I guess it's a typo (`steams` instead of `streams`).

Comment: yes, it's a typo :D thank you.